# Changing src on multiple images - Javascript

Tags: javascript, src

How can I change the source of multiple image-tags using pure JavaScript? I'm making a memory game and if the player unveils two images which do not match I need to reset the source of these two. This is my code for doing this so far:

```
    if (flipLock >= 3) {

        aTag.onclick = null;
        timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
            var reset = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            reset.src = "../pics/0.png";
            flipLock = 0;
        }
        , 1000);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate

```
var reset = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i=reset.length; i--;) {
     reset[i].src = "../pics/0.png";
}
```

Comment: @Tibos -  it iterates the opposite way, yes, but why would that matter.

Comment: @Tibos - Nope, it starts with the last element in the list, and ends with the first -> http://jsfiddle.net/b4QHj/

Comment: Apparently i can't read properly. Didn't see that the decrementation was at the condition check. +1 for the best (and first) answer.

Answer (score 0):

use loop

```
var reset = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i=0; i<reset.length; i++) {
     reset[i].src = "../pics/0.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var reset = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i=0; i<reset.length; i++) {
     reset[i].src = "../pics/0.png";
}
```